# How to split XML child into multiple children based on a delimiter using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML child which contains a bunch of URLs which are delimited by '`|`'

ie.

```
<ImageURL>https://example.com/example.jpg|https://example.com/example2.jpg</ImageURL>
```

I'm trying to write a PHP function which will take each URL and split it into it's own child element. So it should look like below:

```
<ImageURL>
  <Image1>https://example.com/example.jpg</Image1>
  <Image2>https://example.com/example2.jpg</Image2>
  ..etc
</ImageURL>
```

The data is passed into the function as `$value` which is the contents of that ImageURL. Not entirely sure where to start though. Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
function split_images($value){
  ...
}
```

Comment: XSLT is made for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy but it works.

```
<?php
    $xml = '<ImageURL>https://example.com/example.jpg|https://example.com/example2.jpg</ImageURL>';
    //the first `explode` removes the parent tags <ImageURL> so that we can get the child url inside as an array
    $childUrl = explode('|',explode('>',$xml)[1]);
    //I used `var_dump` to make sure that I only get child image `src`
    var_dump($childUrl); //output = array(2) ['https://example.com/example.jpg','https://example.com/example2.jpg']
    //then we created a concatinated parent tag `<imageURL>`
    $imgUrl = '<ImageURL>';
    foreach($childUrl as $key => $value){
        //while using a foreach loop to assign the child url as '<Image></Image>' src
        $imgUrl .= '<Image' . ($key + 1) . '> ' . $value . '</Image' . ($key + 1) . '>';
    }
    $imgUrl .= '<ImageURL>';
    //I used `var_dump` again to test if I get the results you are looking for...
    var_dump($imgUrl); //output = string(132) "<ImageURL><Image1>https://example.com/example.jpg</Image1><Image2> https://example.com/example2.jpg</ImageURL</Image2><ImageURL>"
```

As you can see, the results are in a string format, you can convert then into json or anything you are looking for.

Check it out here [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/523ae769f5e7fab771bf97e3add4b150604165ae)

If it is not what you are looking for, hopefully it will give you some general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not that difficult with DOM:

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<ImageURL>https://example.com/example.jpg|https://example.com/example2.jpg</ImageURL>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// iterate the ImgeURL elements
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//ImageURL') as $imageURL) {
    // read the content and separate the URLs
    $urls = explode('|', $imageURL->textContent);
    // remove the content from the node
    $imageURL->textContent = '';
    // iterate the urls
    foreach ($urls as $index => $url) {
        // add a new Image node and set the url as content
        $imageURL
            ->appendChild($document->createElement('Image'))
            ->textContent = $url;
    }
}

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Numbered (and dynamic) XML are an anti pattern. You should not do this, however you could add the `$index` to the element name.